# Running git not on the working folder

Tags: git

I am in

```
c:\folder1
```

I have a git repositorty in

```
c:\git-porject
```

There is any way, to run `git` on `git-project` without moving to it?

**I dont want to do:**

```
c:\folder1> cd\git-project
c:\git-project> git status
c:\git-project> cd\folder1
```

**I want to do in 1 line:**

```
c:\folder1>git \git-project status
```

But it's not working:

*Error Message*:

> git: '\git\amishared' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-C *path*` argument to switch to git working directory first.

Note however that all the files will be reported relatively to that *path* (such as `git status`, `git add` etc.).